# Object.create, chaining and 'this'

Tags: javascript, object

Given the following program, console logs correctly - note the chained `init` function and `return this`:

```js
const cat = {
  init(sound) {
    this.sound = sound;
    return this;
  },
  makeSound() {
    console.log(this.sound);
  }
};

const fluffy = Object.create(cat).init('meeeaaaauuu');
fluffy.makeSound();
```

My question: **how and why is `return this` required for it to work?**  See error below with it removed:

```js
const cat = {
  init(sound) {
    this.sound = sound;
    // return this
  },
  makeSound() {
    console.log(this.sound);
  }
};

const fluffy = Object.create(cat).init('meeeaaaahuuu');
fluffy.makeSound();
```

MDN states Object.create returns the new object, so chaining init() *should* work...  Thinking it through... *is it because the new object that's chained is still 'anonymous'?*

Note that if `init()` gets its own line, all works as I would expect, without needing `return this`:

```
const fluffy = Object.create(cat);
fluffy.init('meeeaaaahuuu');
fluffy.makeSound();
```

Comment: Your `init` method returns nothing. So `const fluffy` equals to `undefined`. It has nothing to do with `Object.create`.

Comment: Oh - so when chaining a method that doesn't return anything, the original return value (new cat object) is lost?  const fluffy does NOT equal new object with init called on it?

Comment: Do not treat "chaining" as something magical or special. If it was possible I would even legally ban using the "chaining" term: people for some reason put special properties to a function that simply returns something.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason this works:

```
const fluffy = Object.create(cat);
fluffy.init('meeeaaaahuuu');
fluffy.makeSound();
```

is because you're assigning `fluffy` the return value of `Object.create`. When you do `const fluffy = Object.create(cat).init('meeeaaaahuuu');`, you're calling `init` on the return value of `Object.create`, and assigning the return value of `init` to `fluffy`, which is `undefined` without a return statement.

Answer (score 4):

As @zerkms mentions, if `init` lacks a return statement, it will return `undefined`.

In the following line, `fluffy` is getting assigned the value returned by `init`

```
const fluffy = Object.create(cat).init('meeeaaaahuuu');
```

If `init` lacks a returns statement, `fluffy` will be assigned the value `undefined`

```
console.log(fluffy); // undefined
```

If `init` returns the object being assigned to `cat`, then `fluffy` will be assigned that value.

To demonstrate this another way, your chained assignment statement `const fluffy = Object.create(cat).init('meow');` could have been written like this for the same result

```
let fluffy = Object.create(cat);
fluffy = init('meow');
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer!  kyle answered it in a way that was easier on my brain, so I'll give him the check even though both answers look good and helped.  Plus, you're currently on 9,999 rep and that's pretty cool ;)

Comment: np.  i liked @kyle's answer too  :)